# hide second viewcontroller and navigate to third viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, navigation, pushviewcontroller

I am in `ViewControllerA` and other `ViewControllerB` is also loaded in the viewcontroller's `stack.viewControllerB` has camera screen also. 
From `ViewControllerA` I'm calling `ViewControllerB`  by this below code:

```
AppNameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppNameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ViewControllerB *l_ViewControllerB = [appDelegate ViewControllerB];
l_ViewControllerB.view.hidden = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:l_ViewControllerB animated:YES];
```

Now from `ViewControllerB`, I want to switch to `ViewControllerC`.

```
self.view.hidden = YES;
ViewControllerC *l_ViewControllerC = [[ViewControllerC alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:l_ViewControllerC animated:YES];
[l_ViewControllerC release];
```

But its navigating to `ViewControllerA` which I don't need, so I need help, how to navigate to `ViewControllerC` without showing `ViewControllerA`.

Update:
ViewControllerB is defined in ViewControllerB.mm file,there is some C++ coding is also involved in ViewControllerB.mm file.
This will make any difference the ViewControllerB is defined in ViewControllerB.m or ViewControllerB.mm file?

Comment: Why are you hiding that view controller's view?

Comment: is your ViewControllerC does not have xib?

Comment: I am hiding the ViewControllerB's view because that has camera overlay screen which I want to hide/unhide to open/close the camera overlay screen.

Comment: @Gypsa there is xib for ViewControllerC and I have tried this also ViewControllerC *l_ViewControllerC = [[ViewControllerC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2305421?threadID=2305421&tstart=0) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove these two lines, unless there is some reason that you haven't mentioned:

```
// in ViewControllerA:
l_ViewControllerB.view.hidden = NO;

// in ViewControllerB:
self.view.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I am hiding the ViewControllerB's view because that has camera overlay screen which I want to hide/unhide to open/close the camera overlay screen.I am using the barcode scanning sdk to scan the barcode and ViewControllerB belongs to barcode scanning sdk.

Comment: Have you tried not hiding it? Is there a way to just hide the overlay and not the whole view hierarchy?

Comment: I am using i_nigma scanning sdk, in which I don't have access for camera overlay.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe while navigating to `ViewControllerB` i_nigma sdk is creating a new thread. That's why if you try to navigate from `ViewControllerB` to any other view you are not able to navigate, except to ViewControllerA which is already visible.
You can try to perform the action on UI main thread, so that any UI changes are reflected in your UI application. You can try `performSelectorOnMainThread` as below.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(operationComplete) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];
```

You can refer [this](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/08/ios-performselectoronmainthread-with-multiple-objects/) and [this1](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2011/08/ios-performselectoronmainthread-with-multiple-objects/) .